# delta- lognormal GLM

Tags: r, glm, delta

I am trying to model a distribution using a delta-lognormal GLM. My data are abundance (continuous variable with approximately 10%  zeros ) and a series of explanatory variables, but so far I am trying with one at a time.

```
head(data.file)

DENSITY    DEPTH  LONGITUDE LATITUDE  ...(ncol=8)

14.029843    172   9.325000  41.97000    
 8.557391    251   9.367333  42.33000  
17.235731    251   9.367333  42.33000    
37.262910    146   9.159500  42.30300    
19.829688    185   9.238333  42.31900   
... (nrow=12000)
```

I have only found one package that provides this kind of analysis, `fishMod`. I tried the `deltaLN()` command with the following result.

```
deltaLN(DENSITY ~ DEPTH, ~DEPTH, data=data.file)
```

> Error in deltaLN(DENSITY ~ DEPTH, ~DEPTH, data=data.file) : dims [product 12000] do not match the length of object [0]

Any idea what this error stands for and how to amend it? 
Otherwise, do you know about some other package which provides the delta-lognormal GLM?

Answer (score 2):

Package Developer here: this is a bug in the code.  My (stupid) mistake.  It is now fixed for version 25 of the package (and for R-3.1.0).  Please use that from now on.

I have included some example code below, for my debugging from data provided to me by Lucia. It includes a the exact call mentioned above.

On another note: are you sure that you want to use delta log-normal models?  They were included in the fishMod package for 'completeness'.  I have included an alternative in the code below, a Tweedie GLM.  Depending on the data, and the data question, you may want to consider Poisson-gamma models too.  For details see Foster and Bravington (2013) Environ Ecol Stat (2013) 20:533-552.  This is the paper that describes the methods in fishMod.

```
data.file <- read.csv("~/Desktop/data.file.csv") #will need to change on your machine

par( mfrow=c(1,3))

with( data.file, plot( DEPTH, DENSITY, pch=20, main="Raw Data"))
with( data.file, lines( lowess( DEPTH, DENSITY), col="red"))

require( fishMod)
fm.dln <- deltaLN( ln.form= DENSITY~DEPTH, binary.form=~DEPTH, data=data.file)
plot( fm.dln$fitted, fm.dln$residuals[,"quantile"], pch=20, main="Delta Log-Normal quantile residuals")
abline( h=0, col="red")

fm.Tweedie <- tglm( DENSITY~DEPTH, data=data.file)  #estimate power param too!
plot( fm.Tweedie$fitted, fm.Tweedie$residuals[,"random"], pch=20, main="Tweedie GLM Randomised quantile residuals")
abline( h=0, col="red")

#Tweedie has slightly better residuals, slightly only though.

example.model <- deltaLN(DENSITY ~ DEPTH, ~DEPTH, data=data.file) #to check the original problem, very directly.
```

Comment: How do you plot predicted y values of this model over original x vlaues?